# Working in a company without offical contract and not getting paid

Tags: salary, contracts

I am an undergraduate computer engineering student. A friend of mine (not computer engineer)  working in a company as a intern web developer. Two months ago, this company decided to make an android project and they offered us to work with them. Since i am 4th grade and i want to gain some experience before graduation we accepted it even though the salary was really low.

After that I made an unoffical agreement. I work from home and give priority to exams and school projects. They are very understanding about this. Also i decide on deadlines and they setup a meeting at these deadlines to check proggress of the project.

I have not been paid for two months. My project manager keep saying that they need to show a payment for something to pay our salaries because of that we are unoffical workers, otherwise they can not explain this cashout to government.

I have three questions about this story.

1) Since my friend already working there, do they have the right not to pay extra for this project? Please remember that he is working as a web developer in there.

2) Sometimes I have to put deadlines further dates because of my exams and school projects, can they decrease the salary because of this situation?

3) How should i behave against this not being paid situation?

Comment: What they are doing is very likely illegal, but even if it isn't at your location, it is still shady and unethical. You should always demand a contract and refuse to work without one. If they need someone to do their work, they must play by the rules. If you don't have a contract, it would be difficult to prove that they owe you anything. They might change the deal or not pay you at all, it's pretty much up to them.

Comment: Yes but then I won't deliver the project. All codes on my side, I think that is my assurance.

Comment: _All codes on my side_ That's probably they have not paid anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Since my friend already working there, do they have the right not to pay extra for this project?

Not really - that would be like going to a shop buying some bread and expecting the cheese to be for free because you already bought the bread.

> 2) Sometimes I have to put deadlines further dates because of my exams and school projects, can they decrease the salary because of this situation?

I'm not completely sure what it is you're asking - under a proper contract situation, there may be late delivery penalties, but you're not under a proper contract - so the company can do pretty much what they want knowing that you have an almost no ability to fight them over it.

> 3) How should i behave against this not being paid situation?

Stop working for them. You could then request a formal contract, but I get the feeling that this company will likely violate any terms they feel like given your description of the situation up to now.

As Joe has mentioned - this is very likely illegal in most parts of the world, and even if it isn't illegal where you are, it is highly unethical of the employer. Find a more reputable/ethical employer.

Comment: For the second question, for example i can make the first part of the project in a month but because of the exams i say that i can make it 1.5 month. So should i get paid for 1 month or 1.5? And lastly this is illegal as you said. Thanks.

Comment: @Pareidolia Ah, I see... well, no, you should only be paid 1 month for 1 months work in any event...

Comment: You should probably be paid hourly for the time you spend working on the project. If you can't spend much time on the project due to exams, you won't be paid as much. Either way, get some sort of official written employment agreement between yourself and this company if you decide to keep working for them.